# Calculating weighted catchment area

Tags: qgis, r, network-analyst, catchment-area

I would like to calculate the catchment areas of several points in a polygon. It means, I have a city, some POIs in the city and a lot of districts (the centroids). The POIs have different weighting due to the number of persons who use it, and the districts have variable population count. Now, I would like to have the nearest districts to every point separated, which has approximately the same count of people in the sum as the count of people, who use the certain POI.

Is it possible to make calculation like that with QGIS or R, or in worst case with ArcGIS? Or maybe with another tool?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Finally I'm sure that there is no other way to calculate weighted catchment areas except to make a normal OD matrix analysis with ArcGIS (or pgrouting) and then make the calculations and filtering with R or some other statistic program. However, it would be great if somebody made a network analyst extention for QGIS!